# Finding a differentiable inverse of $f(x)=x/\cos x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse

Let $$ 
f:\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$ 
be defined by 
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{\cos x}.
$$

We're supposed to show that $f$ has a differentiable inverse $$f^{(-1)}$$
and to calculate $$(f^{-1})'(0)$$

Can we use the mean value theorem to show $f$ has a differentiable inverse? And how would we then calculate the derivative at $x=0$?

Comment: First, is $f$ one-to-one on that given domain? If so, then it's invertible. Next, is the derivative nowhere zero on that domain? Then there is a formula for $(f^{-1})'$

Comment: The derivative $f'$ is actually continuous on the interval, so if $f'$ is also nowhere zero on the interval, then that would be enough to show that $f$ is one-to-one on the interval.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward application of the [Inverse Function Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem)    The function $f$ is continuously differentiable in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with $f'(0)=1$.  Hence, by the theorem, $f$ is invertible in a neighborhood of $0$, and $f^{-1}$ is continuously differentiable with $(f^{-1})'(0)=1$.